# How to change CheckMark Color of a CheckBox in WP8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am a developing a Windows Phone app. I can't find any properties to change the CheckMark Color for a CheckBox. How do I change the checkmark color for a checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this style and change Fill color in CheckIcon rectangle

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF448DCA"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,0,0"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
      <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddleBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddleBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#EAFFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#F4FFFFFF"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BoxMiddle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To=".55"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0.55"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentFocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                  </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                      <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Width="14" Height="14" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="1"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Fill="#FFC4DBEE" Opacity="0" Width="14" Height="14" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="1" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="BoxMiddleBackground" Width="10" Height="10" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="BoxMiddle" Width="10" Height="10" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" StrokeThickness="1" >
                          <Rectangle.Stroke>
                              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".5,1" StartPoint=".5,0">
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                              </LinearGradientBrush>
                          </Rectangle.Stroke>
                          <Rectangle.Fill>
                              <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.62,0.15" EndPoint="0.64,0.88">
                                  <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.013" />
                                  <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375" />
                                  <GradientStop Color="#EAFFFFFF" Offset="0.603" />
                                  <GradientStop Color="#D8FFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                              </LinearGradientBrush>
                          </Rectangle.Fill>
                      </Rectangle>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="BoxMiddleLine" Width="10" Height="10" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity=".2"/>
                      <Path x:Name="CheckIcon" Margin="1,1,0,1.5" Fill="#FF333333" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0" Width="10.5" Height="10" Data="M102.03442,598.79645 L105.22962,597.78918 L106.78825,600.42358 C106.78825,600.42358 108.51028,595.74304 110.21724,593.60419 C112.00967,591.35822 114.89314,591.42316 114.89314,591.42316 C114.89314,591.42316 112.67844,593.42645 111.93174,594.44464 C110.7449,596.06293 107.15683,604.13837 107.15683,604.13837 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateIcon" Height="2" Fill="#FF333333" Opacity="0" Width="6"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Width="14" Height="14" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                      <Rectangle x:Name="ContentFocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" Width="16" Height="16" />

                      <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed"
                              ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                          <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                              <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" 
                                   Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}"
                                   DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                   Placement="Right" 
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                  <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                          <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                                  <Storyboard>
                                                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                  <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                  </Storyboard>
                                              </BeginStoryboard>
                                          </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                      </EventTrigger>
                                  </ToolTip.Triggers>
                              </ToolTip>
                          </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                          <Grid Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                              <Path Margin="0,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L5,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 7,2 L7,6 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
                              <Path Margin="0,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 7,5 L7,7" Fill="#ffffff"/>
                          </Grid>
                      </Border>

                  </Grid>
                  <ContentPresenter
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click control in the designer -> Edit Style -> Edit a copy

Now you have the whole control style to tinker with. You can change literally everything.
In the *ContentPresenter* part find *Path* control and the *Fill* property is what you want. Change it to whatever color you want and use this style with your control.